# Unique transaction reference in Paypal NVP Masspay response

Tags: paypal, masspay

I need some unique field in Paypal NVP Masspayment so that I can refer that transaction instantly and gather all informations like transaction fee etc.

Please help . At the moment it seems that paypal doesnt return any field to search a specific transaction.

Comment: I did a masspay. Thats it. Had a generic logic for fetching last n transatctions. then loop through them to find transaction equal to my custom_value.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the variable:

> **L_UNIQUEIDn**
>    (Optional) Transaction-specific identification number for tracking in an accounting system.
>   Character length and limitations: 30 single-byte characters. No whitespace allowed.

Ref. 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/

This value can be then collected using **Instant Payment Notification** (IPN) service, please check its functionality [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) and the MassPay values you can collect with IPN are listed [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB070DUI).

For L_UNIQUEIDn, the variable returned with the IPN POST will be:
**unique_id_x**
*For Mass Payments, the unique ID from input, where x is the record number. This allows the merchant to cross-reference the payment
Length: 13 characters*

Comment: is this field also found when using TransactionSearch?